# FOSJsRouting Bundle "The route does not exist"

Tags: ajax, symfony, fosjsroutingbundle

I am trying to generate the route for an Ajax call in my `file.js`. I have installed `FOSJsRoutingBundle` and followed the instruction. I exposed my route for the request but the `Routing.generate()` method gives the error `The route 'ajax' does not exist`. I tested the route with a button and it works.

The Javascript file

```
$('#add_assistant_next').click(function () {
        var route = Routing.generate('ajax');
       var that = $(this);
       var i = $.ajax({
           url: route,
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           data: {"ajax-user": "test user string"},
           async: true,
           success: function (data) {
               $('div#ajax-results').html(data.output);
           }
       });
        return false;
    });
```

The controller route

```
/**
     * @Route(name="ajax", options={"expose" = true}, 
     *         methods={"GET", "POST"}, 
     *          path="/ajax")
     *
     *
     *
     */
    public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
    {
        dump('route called');
        die();
        if ($request->request->get('ajax-user')) {
            dump('request recieved');
            die();
        }

    }
```

Comment: php bin/console debug:route. Did the route appear in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dump your routes every time you add new route 
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html